# ExtJs - Checkbox selection model, disable checkbox per row

Tags: extjs, checkbox, selectionmodel, extjs-grid

I have a grid with a checkbox selection model.

```
Ext.define('Mb.view.ship.OrdersGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    selModel: {
        injectCheckbox: 0,
        pruneRemoved: false
    },
    ...
```

There are some rows that shold not be selectable, based on a value in a field.

In a normal column, I can intervene in the display with `renderer` and hide the cell content with css (`metadata.tdCls`), but for the auto generated checkbox column, I cannot find a method to disable or hide the checkbox on a row basis.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extjs Grid- disable some checkbox on special row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975387/extjs-grid-disable-some-checkbox-on-special-row)

Comment: @rixo No, this is not a duplicate question. In ExtJs there is a column type *checkcolumn* and there is a selectionmodel called *checkboxmodel*. My question refers to the latter, while the other question refers to the first.

Comment: You're right, sorry I haven't seen that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply use the `beforeselect` event of the grid. Returning false, will not allow the selection. Check [the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-beforeselect).

```
Ext.define('Mb.view.ship.OrdersGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    selModel: {
        injectCheckbox: 0,
        pruneRemoved: false
    },

    listeners: {

        beforeselect: function(grid, record, index, eOpts) {
            if (record.get('yourProperty')) {//replace this with your logic.
                return false;
            }
        }

}
..........
```

If you really want to hide the checkbox, you could add CSS classes for your grid rows, and using them you could may be hide them. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637770/in-extjs-how-to-add-a-custom-css-class-to-data-grid-rows) for a solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is already a partial solution. But the user can not know if he can select without clicking. There should be a visual indicator to show if selection is possible.

Comment: Yes but how to you set the checkbox so that it is `disabled` state visually?

Comment: What do you mean by virtually? If you mean in HTML, then... why would one need it?

Answer (score 6):

In ExtJS 6 overriding `renderer` will **not** work.

You can get around that by defining `viewConfig` with getRowClass:

```
            getRowClass: function(record) {
                var classes = '';
                if (!record.get('available')) {
                    classes += ' selection-disabled';
                }
                return classes;
            }
```

Then in your CSS add this:

```
.selection-disabled .x-selmodel-column {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

That will hide selection checkbox.

Now to disable selection by clicking on a row use the standard method. I.e. add a `beforeselect` to `listeners` to `selModel`:

```
        selModel: {
            selType: 'checkboxmodel',
            showHeaderCheckbox: false,
            listeners: {
                beforeselect: function(grid, record) {
                    if (!record.get('available')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Based on your answer I created this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3evu. though I don't know why clearing all the selections by clicking the checkbox in the column header doesn't work (I left it visible). I will have to figure it out.

Comment: @costa Seems like ExtJS checks that not all rows are selected and doesn't allow you to do de-selection. Not sure if you could fix this without overrides. I guess at this point Sencha would have support this case somehow.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! But in my opinion grid looks much better with 'disabled' checkboxes than hidden ones. I'm sharing my modification for all interested: I modified @Nux css class to look like this: .selection-disabled .x-selmodel-column {
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.6;
} That's it.

Comment: @Marcin I don't think you need to worry about IE8 this days . So you probably don't need that filter alpha fallback. Other then that, that sound reasonable too.

Answer (score 1):

CheckboxSelectionModel also has a `renderer`.

```
var sm = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel({
        checkOnly : true,
        renderer : function(v,p,record) {
        // First condition : show
        if (record.data.XXX == 'YYYY') return '<div class="x-grid3-row-checker">&nbsp;</div>';
        // else hide 
        else return '';
    },
    header: ''
});
```

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122496-How-to-hide-certain-checkbox-in-a-CheckboxSelectionModel

Returning empty `''` also disables checkbox selection, not only by hiding it but also adding `unselectable="on"` to the parent div.

Don't know about doing it inside an `Ext.define` (never had the need to extend) , but seems feasible.

**UPDATE:** Despite having `unselectable="on"`, clicking on the row (if enabled), or using the header checkbox (select-all) will select "disabled" rows. It may be a good idea to implement a listener then.