# Ext JS 4: How disable some checkboxes in checkcolumn

Tags: extjs, checkbox, extjs4, hide, selected

I have a grid having a checkcolumn and i want to disable some check boxes. I can get pre-selected them by the dataIndex and can hide with the renderer too. But couldn't disable the pre-selected checkboxes. Here is my checkcolumn code snippet.

```
{
    xtype:'checkcolumn', 
    id:'check',
    width:40,
    dataIndex : 'check',
    renderer: function(value , metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view, returnVal) {
              if (value == false){
                  return Ext.ux.CheckColumn.prototype.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
              }

     }
}
```

Plese kindly help me to figure out hoe to disable the pre selected checkboxes.

Comment: It works perfectly..Thanks for the quick help and I modified some if clauses to fit mine. Thanks again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975387/extjs-grid-disable-some-checkbox-on-special-row

Best Answer..